# How can I add b-table columns in buefy?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I am using buefy's b-table.

I wrote code like `<b-table :data="movies">`, but my movies only have a total of three values.

However, I would like to add the edit and delete buttons to a cell, including the information (3) of the movies in the table.

I unilaterally added the `b-table-column`, but the table line is cut off.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add an action slot

```
<b-table :data="movies">
   <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
     <b-button @click="edit(row)"> Edit </b-button>
     <b-button @click="delete(row)"> Delete </b-button>
   </template>
<b-table />
```

Comment: I do not seem to get an id when I access row rather than props.row. What is the difference between applying row to row rather than props?